# Simple script not working with .prepend() and .css() methods in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, prepend

Today I run into an interesting thing which I don't quite understand. This (see below) very simple jQuery script is not working, basically I want to change the background color of the prepended div to red if the blue == true (which is true).

```
var panel = $("<div id='panel'></div>");
var panelBg = $("#panel");

var test = "true";
var red  = "true";
var blue = "true";


if (test == "true") {


    if (red == "true") {

       $("#first").prepend(panel);

    }



    if (blue == "true") {

       panelBg.css("background-color","red");

    }


}
```

but when I change this line:

```
  panelBg.css("background-color","red");
```

to this:

```
  $("#panel").css("background-color","red");
```

the script works.

working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/wK2jw/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the point when you lookup `#panel`, it does not exist in the DOM yet, therefore this line returns no objects:

```
var panelBg = $("#panel");
```

It works when you do `$("#panel").css("background-color","red");` since this is executed *after* you've added the element with id=panel to the DOM.

Even if `panelBg` did work at the time you assign it, the `panelBg` and `panel` references would be pointing at the same elements anyway, so there doesn't seem to be any point to using two variables to point at the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are assigning an object that does not exist yet in the DOM to a variable.

You could move var panelBg = $("#panel"); to after you prepend your code.

As a side note, you could clean up your code a bit as well, instead of if (test == "true") you could have if (test)